# using V8js in your MAC?

Tags: php, macos, reactjs, v8

My idea is to use reactjs with serverside rendering in PHP. I run and install with success php55-v8js using homebrew. the path of installation is /usr/local/Cellar/php55-v8js/0.4.0_2

in my application I tried to use V8 but with no success. the message displayed is:

> Fatal error: Class 'V8Js' not found in
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/phpreact/index.php on line 14.

on **line 14** the following code is displayed: `$v8 = new V8Js();`

my main question is: do we have to call v8 through a `require_once/file_get_contents->toPath` or similar? or homebrew installation make v8 available globally on the OS system?

Comment: @david-g thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the V8 PECL extension correctly, you also need to turn on the extension in your `.ini` file and restart your PHP server.

Comment: seems to be an ini problem. thks.